# lm(y~x*g) ignoring one value for g

Tags: r, subset, linear-regression, lm

I'm trying to use R for the first time.

In this case, `y` is oxygen consumption, `x` is time and g is status indicated by up to three letters (NYF, IR, F, M, or NF). It will run regressions for each status except for F.

[Side note: I've also tried accomplishing this with multiple regressions using the subset function. When I use

```
lm(O2~time,subset(data,Status=="NYF"))
```

it does not actually adhere to the subset and gives me a regression for the entire data set regardless of which status I enter.

How do I get multiple simple linear regressions from a single data set based on the codes in the `status` column?

Comment: What status column are you talking about? For that matter, what is the context of your question – Excel? Matlab? R? Something else?

Comment: Sorry, I'm using R. "Status" is a column in my data that contains the codes I want to sort the data by.

Comment: You know that doing regression with categorical variable one of them will be the reference? And, by default, it is the first in alfabetical order...

Comment: The regression itself has no categorical variables. Regardless, I've tried pulling out all of the data except that with "F" in the status column, and it just doesn't give me results.

Comment: The subset syntax should be lm(O2~time,subset="Status=='NYF'")

Comment: Maybe the question is not clear..by why it is downvoting? +1 just because you try to use R.

Answer (score 0):

You question isn't clear. Suppose you have a data frame, `dd`, with three columns: `y`, `x`, `g`. The variables `y` and `x` are numeric and `g` takes the values `NYF`, `IR`, `F`, `M`, or `NF`. To carry out simple linear regression for a particular status, then:

```
lm(y ~ x, data=dd[dd$g=="NYF",])
#Or
lm(y ~ x, data=dd[dd$g=="IR",])
```

To perform multiple linear regression, try

```
lm(y ~ x + g, data=dd)
```

where the present or absence of a factor is indicated by a binary variable.

Comment: I'm sorry the question isn't clear, I'm new to R and I don't quite know the correct terminology. Thank you for trying to answer it anyway. Your method appears to work!

Answer (score 0):

lm(y~x,subset(dd,g=='NYF'))

is appropriate syntax to fit the line for a single status (although others are giving you variants that will work). I would check to make sure your data frame is indeed named "data" and your status variable is named "Status".